# How to show keyboard type in numbers in one row in ipad or tab(not multiple rows)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

i have implemented keyboard type number but problem is it is showing bottom center of tab with 4 rows.what i want is to show keyboard in one row only.not mutiple row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to make that choice.  The keyboard is its own app in Android, and it decides what keys are displayed.  You can give it a hint from the type of the field, such as number or email.  But the final decision on what and how to display is the keyboard app's.